# Python Selenium Loop

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, xpath

I am looking to loop this script using a list of values. I have an excel doc with all the `.send_keys` values I would like to use. I was going to leverage openpyxl to pull a list in python. I also can define the list in python and not use openpyxl as well if needed.

Currently I have to copy paste the whole script twice just because I want this script to run with these different send key variables.

```
driver.find_element_by_name("t1st__TBOX").send_keys("619272")
driver.find_element_by_name("t1st__TBOX").send_keys("894323")
```

I have ~100 unique variables so I am looking for a way for `.send_keys` to just reference a list and inject the value and re run the script.

How can I loop this script so it just references a list that has multiple send_keys variables?

Any insight on something that would work would be great!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import unittest, time, re


class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "https://www.website.com/"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True

def test_1(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("https://website.com/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[5]/div/div[2]/img").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    seq = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
    print("Number of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    for x in range(2):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(x)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[3]/td").click()
        except:
            print("It's not: ", x)
            continue
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Email'])[1]/following::td[5]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("t1st__TBOX").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("t1st__TBOX").send_keys("619272")
    print("Number of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))
    for x in range(2):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(x)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='p1st__PDLink']/img").click()
        except:
            print("It's not: ", x)
            continue
    print("Number of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    for x in range(2):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(x)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='p1st__PD_MIRow_1_']/td[3]").click()
        except:
            print("It's not: ", x)
            continue
    print("Number of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    for x in range(2):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(x)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//font/font/input").click()
        except:
            print("It's not: ", x)
            continue
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//font/font/input").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Q619272").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Email").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='null']/option[2973]").click()
    # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [addSelection | id=null | label=Doe, John(johndoe@abcde.com)]]
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Email this Quote'])[1]/following::input[2]").click()
    Select(driver.find_element_by_name("FORMAT")).select_by_visible_text("Text")
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Send").click()
    driver.close()
    ##Round 2##
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://website.com")
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[5]/div/div[2]/img").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    seq = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
    print("Number of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    for x in range(2):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(x)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[3]/td").click()
        except:
            print("It's not: ", x)
            continue
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Email'])[1]/following::td[5]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_name("t1st__TBOX").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_name("t1st__TBOX").send_keys("894323")
    print("Number of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))
    for x in range(2):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(x)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='p1st__PDLink']/img").click()
        except:
            print("It's not: ", x)
            continue
    print("Number of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    for x in range(2):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(x)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='p1st__PD_MIRow_1_']/td[3]").click()
        except:
            print("It's not: ", x)
            continue
    print("Number of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    for x in range(2):
        try:
            driver.switch_to.frame(x)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//font/font/input").click()
        except:
            print("It's not: ", x)
            continue
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//font/font/input").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Q894323").click()
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Email").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='null']/option[2973]").click()
    # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [addSelection | id=null | label=doe, jane(janedoe@abcde.com)]]
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Email this Quote'])[1]/following::input[2]").click()
    Select(driver.find_element_by_name("FORMAT")).select_by_visible_text("Text")
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Send").click()
    driver.close()

def is_element_present(self, how, what):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        return False
    return True

def is_alert_present(self):
    try:
        self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    except NoAlertPresentException as e:
        return False
    return True

def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
    try:
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert_text = alert.text
        if self.accept_next_alert:
            alert.accept()
        else:
            alert.dismiss()
        return alert_text
    finally:
        self.accept_next_alert = True

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)


if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

Comment: You already know what to do, create a list in python, or get the values from reading excel, then loop in it. Is this your whole script, just one/two line?

Comment: Hi Vaibhav conceptually I understand what I need to do, but I am not sure how to code that loop. Also not too sure how to code whats needed using openpyxl to extract a list from excel and use it as a reference point, but I will figure that out once I figure out the loop I suppose. :) For now if I can just figure out a way to loop via a pre defined list that'll work I suppose.

Comment: the whole process of `def test_1` needs to be repeated for every key? Sorry I used selenium a long a ago, I don't quite remember how it works exactly.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the excel in `setUp` and create a list/tuple. Then in `test_1` loop in that list and and put all the current contents of `test_1` inside that loop. That should work.

```
class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.website.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
        # Read excel here to create a list,
        self.my_keys = ('809767', `797978`, ..., )  # or just copy paste the contents of excel here and make a list/tuple yourself.


    def test_1(self):
        for key in self.my_keys:
            # all the previous code of test_1 here
            ...
            driver.find_element_by_name("t1st__TBOX").clear()
            driver.find_element_by_name("t1st__TBOX").send_keys(key)  # use varible key here to send different key each loop
            ...
            # all the previous code of test_1 here
```

This should be enough, might require some changes, because I can't still understand the purpose of methods after `test_1`, I never see you calling them. Also this test might run for a really long time depending on the number of keys you have to send.